# open graph og: tags with url as meta or link

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Using the open graphs usualy looks like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/de/">
<meta property="og:description" content="site description">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.png">
```

*Note: The language of the site is set with /de/ or /en/ and so on.*

Now, the structured data linter tells me
"@de not compatible with range (ogc:url)"

Searching for a solution brought me this git:
[https://github.com/structured-data/linter/issues/49][1]

There its the solution to use `<link />` with attribute `href="https://..."` instead of `<meta />` with attribute `content="https://..."` for URLs.
I've done that, code now looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename">
<link property="og:url" href="https://example.com/de/">
<meta property="og:description" content="site description">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.png">
```

And now the linter tells me
"class ogc:url: No class definition found"

... i'm a bit confused :-P
[1]: https://github.com/structured-data/linter/issues/49

Comment: I haven’t heard of structured-data’s [linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) (I’ve always used Google’s [tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/)). I ran mine, Coke’s, and Apple’s sites through the linter and all had similar errors, *not compatible with range*. You do need the OG meta tags so links can be shared via FB, email, WhatsApp, etc., and the html `lang` attribute is needed for search engines and browsers. Based on gkellogg’s [comment]( https://github.com/structured-data/linter/issues/49#issuecomment-557724934), it seems you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, my solution also is to ignore that warnings. But is it right to use `link` instead of `meta` for urls?

Comment: You should use `<meta` for the OG tags and not a `<link` as Facebook, email programs, and messaging apps (e.g. WhatsApp) look for the OG metadata for constructing rich link previews.